# border for a background image thats inside a text field

Tags: css

How can I apply a 1px solid left border for the magnifying glass image that's inside my text field in this case? It isn't separate.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<style>
input[type=text] {
    width: 260px;
    padding: 5px;
    padding-right: 40px;
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    background-position: 280px 2px;
    background-image: url('http://localhost/icon.png');/* HERE */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

input[type=text]:focus {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-color: #ccc;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px -1px #ccc;
    <!-- background-position: 270px -80px; -->
}

body {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #FFF;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <div id="mainContent">
        <input placeholder="Enter product name..." type="text"> <br>
    </div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Either put it in its own `<img>` element and give it a shadow, or give the `icon.png` a shadow in your favorite image editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to draw the border in the png itself.